# Is there a way of supplying a void function and supplying the innards of function when invoked in another place?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-ref

Basically what I'm trying to achieve is that, let's say that I have a function in a parent component in React. In a child component i want to do some calculation like lets say distance to nearest elements containing box. But I want to invoke this method via a button click or something in the parent. I have refs pointing to my child component and I can achieve this if I add the click to these children. But since I don't have acces to the parent method; how am I to achieve such behaviour?

Here's my child component:

```
import { FC, useRef } from 'react'
import styles from './Card.module.scss'
const Card: FC<CardProps> = ({ image, title, info }) => {
  const cardRef = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null)
  const scroll = (offset: number) => {
    if (cardRef.current) {
      cardRef.current.scrollLeft += offset
    }
  }
  return (
    <div className={styles.card} ref={cardRef}>
      <img src={image} alt={image.split('.')[0]} height={170} width={96} />
      <div className={styles['card-info-container']}>
        <h3>{title}</h3>
        <p>{info}</p>
        <img src="Chevron.svg" alt="Chevron" />
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Card

interface CardProps {
  image: string
  title: string
  info: string
}
```

and here is my parent component:

```
import Card from '../Card/Card'
import styles from './Campaigns.module.scss'
import { campaignData } from '../../mockdata/campaigndata'
const Campaigns = () => {
  const scroll = (offset: number) => {}
  return (
    <section className={styles.campaigns}>
      <h3></h3>
      <div className={styles['cards-container']}>
        {campaignData.map(({ image, title, description }, index) => (
          <Card image={image} title={title} info={description} key={index} />
        ))}
      </div>
    </section>
  )
}

export default Campaigns
```

Comment: Not totally clear... if you add the click to the parent and you are mapping through children how were you planning on determining which child is affected?  Perhaps you could add a bit more code even if it doesn't work

Comment: That's the question actually how could I reach these children and scroll to the next one if they exist @cyberwombat

Comment: Can you not have the click in the child and just pass the parent function to each child? I am not visualizing why you would want the button in the parent. Is there just one button for all the children? That's what a little confusing.

Comment: Wwll the behaviour I'm trying to achieve looks kind of like a carousel only the buttons are a seperate entity and need to be able to go back and forward with clicks @cyberwombat

Comment: Perhaps `useImperativeHandle` is what you are looking for in order to access child function. Here's a post https://www.codingdeft.com/posts/react-calling-child-function-from-parent-component/

Comment: This is somewhat close to what I wan but my answer below doesn't seem to fully work. Like how can I get only the first element that is not visible. If you have any suggestions I'll be happy to recieve them. @cyberwombat

Answer (score 0):

I think I've found a solution but it's not really an elegant one in my opinion. Instead of agonizing over creating refs directly in the child I've opted to create an array of refs from the length of the content using React's `createRef` fucntion here's what I have in my parent component.

```
import Card from '../Card/Card'
import styles from './Campaigns.module.scss'
import { campaignData } from '../../mockdata/campaigndata'
import { createRef } from 'react'
const Campaigns = () => {
  const refs = campaignData.map(() => createRef())
  console.log(refs)
  return (
    <section className={styles.campaigns}>
      <h3></h3>
      <div className={styles['cards-container']}>
        {campaignData.map(({ image, title, description }, index) => (
          <Card
            image={image}
            title={title}
            info={description}
            key={index}
            forwardRef={refs[index]}
          />
        ))}
      </div>
    </section>
  )
}

export default Campaigns
```

Now I can reference every element as a seperate entity and without the hassle